# How to retrieve and replace Null values to another column value in inner join table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

There are four tables. The below i have mentioned in screenshot.

[image]

From the above DeliveryOrder_TBL, NotifyPrtyID NULL then ConsigneeID should replace for that NotifyPrtyID place. How to do??

I want the answer like below.

[image]

check the tables [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32447)

Thanks..

Comment: `COALESCE(NotifyPartyID, ConsigneeID) AS NotifyPartyID`

Comment: Are you attempting to modify the values in the table, or are you attempting to write a `SELECT` query that shows the `NotifyPartyID`, or the `ConsigneeID` if the `NotifyPartyID` is null?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Thanks. i attempt to write a SELECT query. i got the answer using COALESCE function

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT query to retrieved answer, the below code.

```
SELECT DeliveryOrder_TBL.DOID, DeliveryOrder_TBL.DODate, Consignee_TBL.ConsigneeID, Consignee_TBL.ConsigneeName, Shipper_TBL.ShipperID, Shipper_TBL.ShipperName, COALESCE(NotifyParty_TBL.NotifyPartyID, Consignee_TBL.ConsigneeID) AS NotifyPartyID, COALESCE(NotifyParty_TBL.NotifyPartyName, Consignee_TBL.ConsigneeName) AS NotifyPartyName
FROM Consignee_TBL INNER JOIN DeliveryOrder_TBL ON Consignee_TBL.ConsigneeID = DeliveryOrder_TBL.ConsigneeID INNER JOIN Shipper_TBL ON DeliveryOrder_TBL.ShipperID = Shipper_TBL.ShipperID LEFT JOIN NotifyParty_TBL ON DeliveryOrder_TBL.NotifyPartyID = NotifyParty_TBL.NotifyPartyID
```

[image]

Thanks.